# ggplotting st_cast("MULTILINESTRING") lines: ends points undesirably connected to starts using R

Tags: r, sf, well-known-text, plotting

I have the lat-lon positions of various individuals. When I plot multiple individuals at the same time, I see odd lines over land, and have been investigating why. It transpires that plotting multilinestrings in ggplot causes the end points to be connected to their starts, even though I haven't set that anywhere, nor is the connecting point in the data (i.e. the last point isn't a duplicate of the first). Graphically: The entire track of 1 individual:

[image: fulltrack]

Note connecting diagonal line. Only for the year 2012:

[image: 2012track]

Note endpoint (leftmost) now connects to updated start point. By month, 2012 only:

[image: 2012monthly]

Note all months are now loops. Briefly the code I'm using (starting with a data object with individuals & lat & lon & others) is:

```
data %<>%
  sf::st_as_sf(coords = c("lon","lat")) %>%
  sf::st_set_crs(4326) %>% # these are now sf points with geometry
  dplyr::group_by(IndividualID) %>% # and year, month, etc as needed
  dplyr::summarise(do_union = FALSE) %>%
  sf::st_cast("MULTILINESTRING") # are now lines

ggplot() + annotation_spatial(data)
```

But if I make a simple csv with 1 individual with 2 points and another with 3, the second individual's start & end points are not connected (i.e. the image looks as it should):

[image: reprex]

Probing into the data, I looked at the 4th month in the monthly image above:

```
data$geometry[4][[1]]
```

> MULTILINESTRING ((-83.79274 24.62453, ... , -96.15296 27.13187))

I.e. confirming the last point isn't the same as the first, i.e.
`annotation_spatial` isn't just doing what it's told. For what it's worth, using "LINESTRING" has the same effect.

Does anyone have any ideas why this might be?

---

Confounding the issue, most individuals plot just fine:

[image: plotsok]

So I'm especially perplexed as to why some loop back (and continue to do so when split in different ways) whereas most don't, since they're all created from the same processes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let's make a simple random walk with 10 points:

```
> xy = cbind(1:10, runif(10))
> r = st_linestring(xy)
```

Plotting it shows a simple line. The first and last points can be displayed using `st_coordinates`:

```
> plot(r)
> st_coordinates(r)[c(1,10),]
      X         Y L1
[1,]  1 0.8434520  1
[2,] 10 0.2462707  1
```

But suppose somewhere the coordinates were copied twice:

```
> xy2 = rbind(xy,xy)
> r2 = st_linestring(xy2)
> plot(r2)
```

Then the line would appear to be a closed polygon, but the first and last points would still look the same as before:

```
> st_coordinates(r2)[c(1,20),]
      X         Y L1
[1,]  1 0.8434520  1
[2,] 10 0.2462707  1
```

It wouldn't necessarily need to be a complete copy of the coordinates, even a few points repeated from the start of the line would cause a "flyback" and a difference between the first and last coordinates - the last coordinate might not be the end point of the line and you might not notice it.